# PHP Activating account with UPDATE SQL

Tags: php, sql, security

OK I have this code to send an email account verification link

```
      $verifyemail = $clean['email'];
      $to = $verifyemail;
      $subject = 'Virtual Pierz Close | Verify Your Account';
      $message = "Thanks for registering with VPC, on clicking the verification link       below, your account will be confirmed, you can then go ahead buy Virtual Properties,   donating £5 each time to the worthwhile charity.

      http://www.cambrianvacation.co.uk/vpc/registered.php?
      email='$verifyemail'&hash='$hash1' ";

    $headers = 'From:noreply@cambrianvacation.co.uk'; // Set from headers  
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

And then I have this code, that is trying to activate the account by setting active = 1 in the database, which will then be part of the access control logic at login, without active = 1, there is no login, amongst other protection

```
  if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['hash']) &&    !empty($_GET['hash'])){  
  // Verify data  


  $accountemail = $_GET['email'];
  $accounthash = $_GET['hash'];
   }
    $accountActive = 1;
    $notactive = 0;
    $username = '';
    $password2 = '';
    $username = 'xxxxxxx';
    $password2 = 'xxxxxxx';

    $db1 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxxxxxxxxxxx', $username,   $password2, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

   $db1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
   $db1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   try{
   $search = $db1->prepare("SELECT email, hash, active FROM users WHERE email = :email     AND hash= :hash AND active = :active");
   $search->bindParam(':email', $accountemail);
   $search->bindParam(':hash', $accounthash);
   $search->bindParam(':active', $notactive);
   $search->execute();
   $colcount = $search->columnCount();

   }catch(PDOException $e) {
  $e->getMessage();
  } 
       print_r($colcount);
       if($colcount === 3){


      //try{
          $update = $db1->prepare("UPDATE users SET active=:active WHERE email=:email AND hash=:hash AND active = :active");
          $update->bindParam(':active', $accountActive);
          $update->bindParam(':email', $accountemail);
          $update->bindParam(':hash', $accounthash);
          $update->bindParam(':active', $notactive);
          $update->execute();

      //}catch(PDOException $e) {
      // $e->getMessage();
      //}
```

However I cannot get the active column to update.

I've also thought about using the GET['email'] could be subject to semantic url attacks, however the logic won't activate the account without the matching hash, which is randomly generated with crypt().........
If anyone can see any security holes in the code, please tell me.........

Comment: Please stop editing the question without telling anyone that answered you, makes it difficult to try and help and reference what you have if you keep changing it on those trying to help.

Comment: Sorry........I understand the bit about prepared statements well, I just left a bit of there code because I was trying run the code without bindParam and without. Sorry will make sure my code is what it should be next time I publish, as its clearly confusing sorry.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no reason to make two separate queries here.  Why not just have one query to update the record based on hash and email and active = 0? If the count of modified rows = 1, then you had a success, else you had a failure.  You probably don't care why it failed, as it would be bad from a security perspective to indicate back to the user why update failed (i.e. bad email, bad hash, already active user, etc.).

That being said, your problem actually lies in the fact that your update uses `?` style bindings, while you are using `bindParam()` with `:param` style bindings.  This won't work since those values are not present in the prepared statement.

So just use this one single query:

```
UPDATE users SET active = 1 WHERE email = :email AND hash = :hash AND active = 0
```

Obviously if you think you are going to change the value for active/non-active then feel free to use a parameter for those as well, but my guess is you would want to treat that as a boolean-style tinyint field with only allowable values of 0 and 1, so there is really no point in having the parametrization there.

Comment: Sorry I have to sleep......Once I find the solution will post the code...........

Answer (score 0):

Your new parameters are not bound correctly, change:

```
$update = $db1->prepare("UPDATE users SET active=? WHERE email=? AND hash=? AND active = ?");
```

To:

```
$update = $db1->prepare("UPDATE users SET active=:active WHERE email=:email AND hash=:hash");
```

**EDIT - Full Update Code:**

```
      $update = $db1->prepare("UPDATE users SET active=:active WHERE email=:email AND hash=:hash");
      $update->bindParam(':active', $accountActive);
      $update->bindParam(':email', $accountemail);
      $update->bindParam(':hash', $accounthash);
      $update->execute();
```

Comment: Yeah I've changed that, sorry published the code wrongly as I've been trying different things.....:-/

Comment: @AntPower With the code you are showing now, you want to update the last `?` to `:hash`, and remove `AND active = active` ^^  (You don't need to check again to make sure they aren't activated yet, as you did that in the initial select query)  (EDIT: also remove `$update->bindParam(':active', $notactive);`, you are resetting the parameter now, so it will change/keep it as non-active)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is not include "email" at all.

You could try to gen the url by doing this:

```
$secret = "1032940fdjsjdkf#@$!@#%djsfisd";
$hash = md5($email.$secret);
$url = "http://www.cambrianvacation.co.uk/vpc/registered.php?hash=".$hash;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the update query, you are using "?" for parameters, but then you try to set them as named with bindParam(). You should use

```
$update->execute(array($accountActive, $accountemail, $accounthash, $notactive));
```

Or modify the update query this way:

```
$update = $db1->prepare("UPDATE users SET active=:active WHERE email=:email AND hash=:hash");
```

Comment: I've tried both ways, neither are updating the active column in the mySql database, I prefer to use bindParam...

Comment: And if you remove the slashes that comment out the last try/catch group, does it give you any error? Maybe you can understand what's going on. I wonder if you need to close the cursor before the UPDATE query, using 
    $update->closeCursor();